# Diode marking code KE OB, what could that diode be?

Tags: diodes, identification

I need the datasheet of this diode. The code written is KE OB or could be KE 0B.

[image: photo of component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's one of these [tranzorbs.](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88392/smbj.pdf) SMBJ5.0A has the KE marking, 0B is the date code for Nov 2010.